# Oracle Apex - Get URL from Image stored as Blob in table

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page where I'm trying to display an image - stored as blob - along with a link (to later use as an img html source).
This is my query to display stored images on table:

```
select
id,
DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(BLOB_DOCUMENT) IMAGE, -- to display my image
MIMETYPE_DOCUMENT,
IMAGE_NAME
from my_table
```

I'm  using a classic report but can use an Interactive one if needed.
How can I get and display an URL for the image?
I know one can do this when storing images into the Static Application files folder, however, we need users to load images on the front-end (thus this option not working cause of authorization).
Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed tutorial to show image in report.

URL: https://www.javainhand.com/2020/04/display-images-into-reports-in-oracle-apex.html

**How-to:**

Set your image blob column's attributes to -

`Identification > Display Image`

`BLOB Attributes > Update/Select corresponding values`

Then, give an ID to your IR, example "MY_PHOTO". Place these CSS in page's `CSS > inline` and adjust your desired image size there.

```
#MY_PHOTO img {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px; /* any size you want */
    height: auto;
}
```